# Python multiple elif alternatives

Tags: python

I have a script which needs to iterate through thousands of various different, but simple options.

I can use if...elif to iterate through them, but am wondering if there is a faster / better option than thousands of elifs. For example

```
if something == 'a':
    do_something_a
elif something == 'b':
    do_something_b
elif something == 'c':
    do_something_c
elif something == 'd':
    do_something_d
...
A thousand more elifs
...
else:
    do_something_else
```

The thing I will be doing will usually be running a function of some kind.

Comment: It depends on where `something` comes from. Is it user input of some kind?

Comment: It would be a variable value, generally taken from a column in a database which I am iterating through.

Comment: You can try using a dictionary...

Comment: sounds like you could do this with a dict

Answer (score 4):

you can use a dictionary to control mutliple possible logical paths:

```
def follow_process_a():
   print('following a')

def follow_process_b():
   print('following b')

keyword_function_mapper = 
{'a' : follow_process_a ,
 'b' : follow_process_b,                     
}

current_keyword = 'a'
run_method = keyword_function_mapper[current_keyword]
run_method()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! If you want you can also mark this answer as accepted answer if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dictionary for that in this way:

```
def do_something_a():
    print 1

def do_something_b():
    print 2

dict = {'a': do_something_a, 'b': do_something_b}
dict.get(something)()
```

Comment: thank you, I fixed `;`
I expected that do_something_a() function is already exist. so this code will call it if something == a

Comment: @melpomene thank you that showed me that. you are absolutely right. I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to create a dictionary which maps the somethings to their respective function. Then you can apply this dictionary to the data.

More information: https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html
(Dictionary Mapping)